# How can I get NUnit3TestAdapter to work with .Net Standard 2.0?

Tags: nunit, .net-standard

How can I get NUnit3TestAdapter to work with .Net Standard 2.0?

I receive the following error:

> 1>C:\Nikeza\Mobile\Nikeza.Mobile\Tests\ExampleBased.fsproj :
>
> warning NU1701: Package 'NUnit3TestAdapter 3.9.0' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
>
> This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
>   1>ExampleBased ->
>   C:\Nikeza\Mobile\Nikeza.Mobile\Tests\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ExampleBased.dll

Comment: Make no sense not targeting the tests to NetStandard. If I have a conditional flow in my code that only happens when it's NetStandard it won't be tested. It's not my case in the moment. Basically all I have falls into Netcore or NetFramework and netstandard flows thru netcore in this case. But it's something to think about

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't provide enough information to diagnose what is wrong with your project file, but it 3.9.0 of the NUnit Adapter does work with .NET Standard 2.0 and F#. I think that your test project is targeting .NET Standard. It needs to target .NET Core or .NET 4.6.1+. Test projects are treated like executables, they need to target a specific framework, not .NET Standard. The code that you are testing can be .NET Standard though.

You should follow the documentation [Unit testing F# libraries in .NET Core using dotnet test and NUnit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-fsharp-with-nunit) and read the NUnit docs, [.NET Core and .NET Standard](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard).

Your project file should look something like this,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Tests.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MathService\MathService.fsproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Why is `netcoreapp2.0` required? I expected `netstandard2.0` to be sufficient for a library with tests. Obviously I'm misunderstanding, but please help me.

Comment: `netcoreapp2.0` is required because that is the way the .NET Team designed it. They decided you must decide which platforms you want to run your tests on by compiling your tests that way. They could probably have loaded .NET Standard tests into platform specific runners based on command line options, but they didn't. If they did it that way, you would always have to specify what platform you want to run under. This way, if you single-target your tests, they just know. Think of it like a console app, you can't create or run a .NET Standard console app, you must specify a target.

Comment: So you're saying that every time you create a UnitTest library based on .NET Standard you will have to edit the .csproj file to target a specific framework?

Comment: @JoshMonreal all you need to do is create your unit test library as a .NET Core library and not a .NET Standard library. It is just the way testing works in .NET Standard, it isn't an NUnit, xUnit, etc issue.

Comment: @RobProuse: Perhaps I'm missing something here so apologies for my question. How will I create my unit test library as a .NET core library? When I tried to create a new class library in Visual Studio 2017 the only options are .NET Framework and .NET Standard. .NET Core is only available for Console and ASP.NET applications.

Comment: @JoshMonreal, in my install of Visual Studio 2017 15.8 I have a project Class Library (.NET Core) listed under Installed | Visual C# | .NET Core in the Add New Project dialog.

Comment: modify the element TargetFramework to be: `  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`

Comment: The problem with this is that most other packages target netstandard, so forcing me to choose netcore means a bunch of packages I cant use due to NU1701 package install failures and rollbacks. Really, Really, frustrating!.

Comment: For the record, I got this error in a project I didn't intend to test (a test framework library). It was because it was in a folder with the same `Directory.Build.targets` file that unintentionally imported `NUnt3TestAdapter` into my test framework assembly. Targeting `.netstandard2.0` was intentional, importing `NUnit3TestAdapter` was not.

Comment: @StingyJack - Why is that a problem? Do you have your tests in the same library you ship? The library under test can target `netstandard2.0`, but the library that contains the tests must target an executable platform that is compatible with `netstandard2.0` so they can be run.

Comment: @nightowl888 - I forget the specifics at this point, and started a new job since then so I can't go looking it up. Nuget was complaining big time and this package was causing it. Another developer brought it to me as a problem they were having and I could repro it. If I can recall the details I'll reply/update, but it seems odd that mstest can use a netstandard project with tests but nunit makes me change the project type and possibly a bunch of dependencies along with it.